# как сохранить список данных в бд python/django

Tags: python, django, парсер

Допустим на простом примере, у меня есть парсер, он возвращает мне список данных, например, заголовков статьи и ссылок на них.

Например:

список названий

```
titles = ['Главы МИД ЕС обсудят возможный бойкот Олимпиады в Пекине', 'Зеленский рассказал о «шлагбауме» на пути Украины в НАТО', 'Главы МИД ЕС обсудят возможный бойкот Олимпиады в Пекине', 'Главы МИД ЕС обсудят возможный бойкот Олимпиады в Пекине']
```

и список ссылок к ним

```
links = ['https://lenta.ru/news/2021/12/10/obsud/', 'https://lenta.ru/news/2021/12/10/shlagbaum/', 'https://lenta.ru/news/2021/12/10/obsud/', 'https://lenta.ru/news/2021/12/10/obsud/']
```

Как мне записать это в бд, чтобы в бд оно хранилось: для первого заголовка в titles первая ссылка в links

код модели django

```
class Test(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
 link = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Comment: `for i in zip(title, link): Test.objects.create(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что вам стоит помещать title и link в модель статьи и тогда не будет этой проблемы

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]